# Spring Security /login page: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect, spring-security

The /login page throws me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS every time. I've looked through almost everything.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
//  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
//  testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'

    // lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'

    // spring security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    //  Temporary explicit version to fix Thymeleaf bug
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

org.example.demo.entity.User:

```
package org.example.demo.entity;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password_hash")
    private String passwordHash;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        if (isAdmin()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        } else {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        }

        return authorities;
    }

    private boolean isAdmin() {
        return true;
        // TODO check if user is admin
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

org.example.demo.securingweb.WebSecurityConfig:

```
package org.example.demo.securingweb;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

org.example.demo.repository.UserRepository:

```
package org.example.demo.repository;

import org.example.demo.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

org.example.demo.dto.UserDTO:

```
package org.example.demo.dto;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class UserDTO {
    private String email;
}
```

org.example.demo.service.UserService:

```
package org.example.demo.service;

import org.example.demo.dto.UserDTO;
import org.example.demo.entity.User;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserService {
    User createUser(UserDTO userDTO, String password);
    User changePassword(UserDTO userDTO, String newPassword);
    void deleteUser(Long userId);
    User getUserByEmail(String email);
    List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

org.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl:

```
package org.example.demo.service;

import org.example.demo.dto.UserDTO;
import org.example.demo.entity.User;
import org.example.demo.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public User createUser(UserDTO userDTO, String password) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        user.setPasswordHash(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User changePassword(UserDTO userDTO, String newPassword) {
        User user = getUserByEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        if (user != null) {
            user.setPasswordHash(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
            return userRepository.save(user);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User not found with email: " + userDTO.getEmail());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long userId) {
        userRepository.deleteById(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserByEmail(String email) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        return userOptional.orElse(null);
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

org.example.demo.controller.UserController:

```
package org.example.demo.controller;

import org.example.demo.dto.UserDTO;
import org.example.demo.entity.User;
import org.example.demo.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO, @RequestParam String password) {
        User user = userService.createUser(userDTO, password);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(user);
    }

    @PutMapping("/change-password")
    public ResponseEntity<User> changePassword(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO, @RequestParam String newPassword) {
        User user = userService.changePassword(userDTO, newPassword);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred");
    }
}
```